# how would you change Android AVD setting to make the emulator smooth as on the real android devices?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, smoothing, setting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

**this is my setting:**
Name = JellyBean_x86, Target = Android 4.1 - API Level 16, CPU/ABI = Intel Atom (x86),
SD Card = 2048 MB, Snapshot enabled, Skin = WVGA800, Abstracted LCD density = 240, Max VM application heap size 48, Device ram size = 512.

It runs well with Intel Core i5-M540 on and 8 GB of RAM on my laptop, but it isn't as smooth and fast as I thought it will be. In fact, changing the CPU setting from x86 to ARM won't give notable difference. What else could we do to tweak them?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try setting WVGA400? Smaller resolution makes everything faster...

Comment: I have a core i3 M350, and using Intel processor is at least 5 times faster then using ARM. I'll try to investigate.

Comment: Do you have Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) installed for Intel Atom x86 ?

Comment: Go to your computer BIOS setup and confirm that you VT enabled. Start the emulator, and confirm that HAXM is running (in windows machine type "sc query intelhaxm" at command prompt). Let me know the result.